# Какая разница между лишь и только?

Tags: выбор-слова, правописание, синонимы

Я еще не нашел подробную инфорнацию об этих словах, то есть я бы хотел знать, 
когда надо писать слово "только", и когда надо писать "лишь"?

Есть ли случаи, когда можно менять "только" на "лишь" (и наоборот) без потери смысла?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: лишь is something like "merely"—It's "only" in the sense of "merely"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Предлог "лишь" подчеркивает малость, незначительность. Предлог "только" не имеет такой окраски.

Пример:

```
Пропускать только посетителей с билетами!
```

Здесь использование предлога "лишь" недопустимо, поскольку посетителей с билетами может быть много.

```
Летать только на исправных самолётах.
```

Аналогично. Исправных самолётов может быть больше, чем неисправных, поэтому "лишь" недопустимо.

```
Они принимают заявления только на испанском языке.
```

Говорящий констатирует факт и обращает внимание на необходимость перевести заявление, если оно на другом языке.

```
Они принимают заявления лишь на испанском языке.
```

Говорящий с сожалением подчеркивает, что количество языков, на которых можно написать заявление, мало и не соответствует ожиданиям.

Answer (score 4):

Абсолютно взаимозаменяемые слова. Нет никакой разницы. Автор строк про самолеты и билеты в корне не прав. Говорю, как филолог. И эти слова не предлоги, а союзы. 
Изначально союз "только" означал "столько, сколько есть", а "лишь" употреблялся в значении "свыше, больше". Теперь же их употребление регулируется скорее нормами благозвучия, чем семантикой.

Comment: Как написал @Anixx "лишь" имеет оттенок сожаления. Встречается обычно в возвышенно-поэтическом контексте: "один лишь раз сады цветут".

Answer (score 3):

Я зашел сюда случайно и, если я правильно понял, это вопрос человека, который учит русский язык. Я русский.
Постараюсь ответить.
Разницы между "только" и "лишь" особой нет, но "лишь" употребляется реже. Если не знаете, что употреблять, говорите "только", хотя в любом случае это, скорее всего, будет нормально звучать.
Пример:

> Я знаю только русский язык.
>   Я знаю лишь русский язык.

Оба варианта нормально звучат.  (Примера неправильного употребления не смог придумать)

Также есть союз "лишь только", означающий "как только", "сразу после того, как"

> Он начинал трепетать, лишь только она появлялась.

Comment: Можно сказать и "Я знаю только лишь русский язык".

Comment: @Artemix - Можно даже сказать "Я знаю лишь только русский язык". ;-)

Comment: Хороший ответ. +1 от меня. Добавлю. Как мне кажется, слово "лишь" имеет некоторый драматический оттенок. Оно немного театральное и поэтическое. Слово "только" — нейтральное. Если хотите немного драматизировать фразу, то слово "лишь" вполне подходит. Учитывайте эти оттенки значения.

Answer (score 1):

**Есть ли разница в употреблении "только" и "лишь"?**

Частица ***только*** относится к определенному числовому интервалу и используется, если нужно обозначить его **ограниченность**. Это нейтральный стиль, сообщение информационного характера.

Частица ***лишь*** подчеркивает исключительность указанного временного отрезка и по контексту может иметь дополнительную **коннотацию.** Стиль ближе к разговорному.

2. Если сравнить практические примеры с частицами ***только*** и ***лишь***, то можно увидеть следующее: частица  ***лишь*** не меняет основное содержание сообщения, но предполагает дополнительные смысловые **оттенки**.

**Примеры дополнительной коннотации для частицы "лишь"**

*Сдать зачёт можно **лишь** с 10:00 и до 14:45.* (И не надо приходить раньше или позже.) Разговорный стиль.

*Магазин работает **лишь** до восьми вечера.* Ну и магазин!

*Антон пробежал **лишь** пять километров.* Больше не осилил, а говорил, что десять пробежит.

*Он вышел погулять **лишь** на пятнадцать минут.* Не думал, что его отсутствие заметят.

Источник:  [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/480198/Есть-ли-разница-в-употреблении-только-и-лишь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/480198/%D0%95%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%8C)

3. Приведенные в предыдущем ответе примеры с частицей ***только*** не показались мне удачными (я увидела их в Сети и обратила на них внимание).

— *Пропускать **только** посетителей с билетами!*  — А раньше что, без билетов пропускали?

— Летать ***только*** на исправных самолётах. — А раньше что, на неисправных летали?

Comment: Answers and questions should be self-contained so that link rot won't affect them. Can you please add the relevant information from the linked article to your post, and amend it so that it would answer the question as asked? Thank you!

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, я исправила по возможности.